# Loop not Looping?

Tags: java, android, math

I'm having difficulty getting my program to loop. `gameloop()` is called in `onCreate`. I then have a button which calls `questions()`. Just want to display ten questions into the textview and it update every time the submit button is clicked. Any help would be fantastic.

```
int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));
int answer;

int q1 = random1 + random2;
int q2 = random1 - random2;
int q3 = random1 / random2;
int q4 = random1 * random2;
```

The above are declared.

```
public void gameloop(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i1 == 1) {
            answer = q1;
            editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "+" + random2);
            continue;
        }
        if (i1 == 2) {
            answer = q2; 
            editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "-" +random2);
            continue;
        }
        if (i1 == 3) {
            answer = q3;
            editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "/" +random2);
            continue;
        }  
        if (i1 == 4) {
            answer = q4; 
            editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "*" +random2);
            continue;
        }
    }
}

public void questions() {

int score = 0;
int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());       
if (i == answer) {
    score ++;
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "/" +random2);
    gameloop();
}
else {
    editTextEquation.setText(random1 + "*" +random2);
    gameloop();
}
```

Comment: What is the value of i1?

Comment: what is 'i1'? the .setText(something) will destroy whatever is in editTextEquation. If thats your textview you will write to it 10x, but only the last write will be there

Comment: Yes, according to what you have written, `i1`s value does not change during the loop, hence why the loop?

Comment: sorry i updated it. i1 is just a random number, so I can generate random questions.

Comment: ah I see what I might be doing wrong. How do I get i1 to keep churning out a random value between 1 and 4?

Comment: ahh I just moved - int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

Answer (score 1):

You're looping 10 times and doing the same thing on each iteration. Why?

Also, you say:

> Just want to display ten questions into the textview

Where are the *ten* questions? You're only setting the text in *one* text-box.

It sounds like you want a *collection* of text-boxes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only 1 text box, as shown in your code, you may want to create a collection of objects with a question and the available answers. Then you could create them upon initialization and swap them out for another object when the submit button is hit. That way you are reusing the same controls in the UI.